# Run emacs in Terminal using AppleScript

Tags: emacs, terminal, applescript

I wish to create an AppleScript application in Xcode that launches Terminal and runs `emacs`. I would also like it to type <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> after it finishes and follow that with whatever emacs program I need to run. I've tried `do shell script "emacs"` but the log output is

`[XXAppDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:]: emacs: standard input is not a tty (error 1)`

and that still does not solve the issue of typing in <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> later.

Being new to AppleScript, I don't know much beyond basic commands, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found this to work:

> ```
> tell application "Terminal"
>      set currentTab to do script "emacs"
> end tell
>
> tell application "Terminal" to activate
> tell application "System Events" to key code 53
> ```

This makes the current tab (or  new tab) of Terminal run emacs and type <kbd>Esc</kbd>.